# Android webservices connection refused

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I am trying to access RESTful webservice from android using below code.

```
ClientConfig config= new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client=Client.create(config);
    WebResource service=client.resource("http://localhost:8085/JerseyTest/jersey/test/testing123");
```

But am getting the following exception.

07-22 16:53:15.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1491): Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8085): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

But the url is working well in broswers and i also tried with firewall turned off.Anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, You should change localhost by the ip of the computer where you have the WebService

Answer (score 0):

Check whether u have added all the permission required and try IP address instead of localhost